# TypeScript type restriction difference between class and interface with never

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've written a `class` in TypeScript which I now wanted to convert into an `interface` with multiple implementations. There I discovered a case where `never` became assignable by anything, which previously failed (and should fail), but after using the `interface` it suddenly passed.

Here's the code:

```
class A<TX, TY> {
    #x?: TX | undefined;
    #y?: TY | undefined;
}

interface B<TX, TY> {
    // i don't want x and y to be public
}
```

When removing the private properties the class behaves the same as the interface, which is not desired. So basically I'm looking for a way to make the interface behave like the class, but without modifying its public properties and methods.

The test code, where the `never` handling is changed:

```
function a(i: boolean): A<number, never> {
    // the return type must be A<number, 'str'> for this to work

    if(i) {
        return new A<never, 'str'>(); // error: Type 'A<never, "str">' is not assignable to type 'A<number, never>'.
    }

    return new A<number, never>(); // no error
}

function b(i: boolean): B<number, never> {
    // here should be an error, because the return type must be B<number, 'str'> for this to work

    if(i) {
        return null as unknown as B<never, 'str'>; // no error, but why?
    }

    return null as unknown as B<number, never>; // no error
}
```

The behavior of the return type should follow these rules:

- if the generic in the return type is `never`, only `never` is allowed
- if the generic in the return type is non-never `T`, then `T` or `never` is allowed

```
// should pass:
function a(): A<never, never>   { return new A<never, never>(); }
function a(): A<string, number> { return new A<never, never>(); }
function a(): A<boolean, never> { return new A<true, never>(); }
function a(): A<string, string> { return new A<never, 'foo'>(); }

// should fail:
function a(): A<never, never>   { return new A<string, never>(); }
function a(): A<never, never>   { return new A<never, boolean>(); }
function a(): A<never, string>  { return new A<string, never>(); }
function a(): A<boolean, never> { return new A<never, number>(); }
```

Or maybe there's different approach that works better for this use case?

TypeScript PlayGround Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAGgGmogmgPmgbwChpjoBiADwH4AuDZaAH2gFcA7AEwFMAzAS1c7sA3ERKkAnjQyZGLDj36CRo4mAAUYWmoBuYEM060UASmgBeXACMA9tZCcwrY7QQp0WXHmgAnTgBdmb1ZoVmYQEGhISNZxIWgAXxVoSyQAJU4IML9sNUstXX1DOlMLDHTMkD9nODSMrPccfB9-QODQ8MiYR1iEkUSCfj9Ob24wYE5oACEkNGlPJIB6BeheaHZrVgByP2gAd0cd8mj2aHFoP2tkiYAHZksQXmACJPVNaB09AyNkEqtbe0c1WmbjmIhIyVqFWyuXynyKJnMuEQ5SyQMh9VBBH63DYwD8vA2kTUvFoNjsDicLngoQAtpZhugBNphvNwUtzgALCa+AJBc7ia4TGnMCA7ek1Wn07zoTai7ybXDcazeTm8GAXPbKgDWz3BvG4xNMhHB4J5rRCnF2Es4zOl0FlfnlOWMcXZw28yqMAommwQTIZ0AARHLA9hNisYKxrDtIBBeABzVhge4TDV+b32v3MOkB-3eMMAOiS-VNLT5AitWZzdrzztdyyj0HdyqxzxxrDxBOClmJpP+FLRktzNpZ+EWyy5vmgEA51jCJ3Fjib3g9dvpwDAItTXOavOC6cF0GFoquU2p2alMrlCugSpVfg5avOl122t1JH1hrHJpIZvLYQiKI2C1KNdmCKJpjzK9HQVesQkuZs12YHZdg5SRi3fYg-zaADOjkEDrDAvDIIvYdbWwODG0QrEgA

Comment: Your interface is empty, so no matter what arguments you pass the result type will always be `{}` and that's why `B<number, never> ` is the same thing as `B<never, 'str'>`

Comment: It doesn't change when I add methods to it. I'll add a link to a typescript playground example

Comment: Now the problem is that `never` is an empty set, which is a subtype of every type.
`type Case1 = never extends 1 ? true : false; // true` and `type Case2 = never extends 'str' ? true : false; // true`

Comment: You will have to change your strategy to not use never or adding some custom redundant code to prevent the error

Comment: . @BenjaminM because if you add `xx: TX; yy: TY` to B it'll work as you expected. TY in invisible atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might seem to be using the branding trick:

```
const _XBrand: unique symbol = Symbol("_XBrand");
const _YBrand: unique symbol = Symbol("_YBrand");

export interface B<TX, TY> {
    // i don't want x and y to be public
    [_XBrand]: TX | never,
    [_YBrand]: TY | never,
}

// should pass:
function b1 (): B<never, never> { return null as unknown as B<never, never>; }
function b2 (): B<string, number> { return null as unknown as B<never, never>; }
function b3 (): B<boolean, never> { return null as unknown as B<true, never>; }
function b4 (): B<string, string> { return null as unknown as B<never, "foo">; }

// should fail:
function b5 (): B<never, never> { return null as unknown as B<string, never>; }
function b6 (): B<never, never> { return null as unknown as B<never, boolean>; }
function b7 (): B<never, string> { return null as unknown as B<string, never>; }
function b8 (): B<boolean, never> { return null as unknown as B<never, number>; }
```

Firstly, you declare private symbols _XBrand and _YBrand, then you use them as properties of your interface. They serve the same purpose as private properties in a class; external files have no means to declare or use these. There is almost no cost at runtime as these properties will never be initialized.